# Unable to declare functor type that takes zero parameters?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to make a type definition for the function type () => Unit, I use this signature quite a bit for cleanup callback functions, and I'd like to give them more meaningful names.

I've tried the following, which I think should be correct syntax, but it doesn't compile:

```
package myPackage

import stuff

type CleanupCallback = () => Unit

trait myTrait ...

class mObject ...
```

Why doesn't it compile?  And what is the correct syntax?

The compilation error is: expected class or object definition

Comment: Works for me in Scala 2.12.6

Comment: Also you can try `type CleanupCallback = Function0[Unit]`

Comment: Neither works for me.  How do I find the version of Scala I'm using?  I'm using intellij with the scala plugin

Comment: Where are you putting this line and what error are you getting? It is hard to know what is wrong without more detail and context.

Comment: I've updated the example to show; it's after the package and imports, but before other definitions within the file.  It's in the scope of the file, not within any other definition.

Answer (score 2):

You can't declare type alias out of `class/trait/object` scope. But you can declare it in **package object** as follows:

```
package object myPackage {
  type CleanupCallback = () => Unit
}
```

It will be visible for all classes in `myPackage`.

Also you can import it in other classes which belong to other packages:

```
import myPackage.CleanupCallback 

trait MyTrait {
  def foo: CleanupCallBack
}
```

IDEA plugin supports creation of package objects, another version is (suppose you don't have IDEA plugin):

Create file `package.scala` in your package. The file must contain:

```
package object packageName { // name must match with package name
  // ...
}
```